# AngularJs variable scope outisde function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

I am getting data using socket into angularJS controller.

```
$rootScope.list1= '';
socket.emit('ticker', symbol);
socket.on('quote', function(data) {
    $rootScope.list1 = angular.fromJson(data.substring(3));
//I can't call any function from here to use this variable
});
```

I want to use updated list1 variable in my code below but I am not able to as it's value is coming as ''.
This can be because I am trying to access it in my script prior to it being updated i.e. prior to the response received.

Is there any way where I can use the updated value of variable list1 in my code below.

## Edit 1

As suggested by @Manish Singh in one of the answers, I tried $rootScope.watch.It is reflecting new value for above peice of code but not for code given below.

```
$rootScope.peers = [];
industrysearch.searchindustry(indussymbol).then(function(results) {
  industrysearch.searchpeers($scope.industrystock[0]._source.industry).then(function(results1) {
            for (var number_stocks = 0; number_stocks < results1.length; number_stocks++) {
                $rootScope.peers.push(results1[number_stocks]);
            }
        });
    });
    $rootScope.$watch('peers', function(newVal1, oldVal1) {
      console.log(newVal1); //prints []
    });
```

one is normal variable and one is used as array.I can;t see any other difference.

## Edit 2

$watchCollection is use for arrays/collection which I missed.Below code is working.

```
$rootScope.$watchCollection('peers', function(newVal1, oldVal1) {
      console.log(newVal1);
    });
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: updating scope variables inside events, you have to use $scope.$apply() for the changes to be updated outside the event

Comment: I tried adding $scope.apply but it did not work.
socket.on('quote', function(data) {
$scope.$apply(function() {
 $rootScope.list1 = angular.fromJson(data.substring(3));
});
 //I can't call any function from here to use this variable
});

Answer (score 0):

How about using a watch on $rootScope

```
$rootScope.$watch('list1', function(newVal, oldVal) {
//Do Something 
)};
```

Comment: $watch worked here but just to print the updated value.We can't use this value in loop etc as a variable.As I have multiple variable so I cant use $watch for each of them and then use all values together.

Comment: Yes the $watchCollection would be the most apt here, and I think you don't have much experience with $watch services. [this](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-scope-watch-vs-watchcollection-in-angularjs.htm) was helpful for me to understand the various concepts. And also It'd be great if you could accept my answer, as it was sufficient for your first question. Even so, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try "$applyAsync":

```
$rootScope.list1= '';
socket.emit('ticker', symbol);
socket.on('quote', function(data) {
    $rootScope.$applyAsync(function(){
       $rootScope.list1 = angular.fromJson(data.substring(3));
    });
});
```